# How to check if an element exists in xpath and return null/no value if it doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape data from a website given a list of urls which is stored in "data".

I noticed some urls don't have the xpath to "og_price" and "discount" and I get an error of NoSuchElement or just straight saying "og_price" and "discount" is not defined presumably because the certain url doesn't have that xpath.

I want to check if an xpath exists in a url (which I tried to do with try-except) and return a null value or just string "no" but I am stuck on how to do that as I later call ".text" on "og_price" and "discount" which will say 'str' object has no attribue '.text'

```
for url in data:
    driver.get(url)
    item_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="productTitle"]')
    brand_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="a-spacing-small"][.//*[contains(.,"Brand")]]/td[@class="a-span9"]/span')
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-micro"]/span[@id="price_inside_buybox"]')
    try: 
        og_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="priceBlockStrikePriceString a-text-strike"]')
        discount = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="a-span12 a-color-price a-size-base priceBlockSavingsString"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        og_price = null
        discount = null
    

    row = { 'Item Name': item_name.text,
            'Brand Name': brand_name.text,
            'Price': price.text,
            'Original Price': og_price.text,
            'URL': url
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Harry Kim the proper way of checking if a element exists is by wraping the check in the try/catch block as you did above. To resolve the issue of null object exception, you can have a if check before assigning the element to the row map. Something like,

```
    try: 
        og_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="priceBlockStrikePriceString a-text-strike"]')
        discount = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="a-span12 a-color-price a-size-base priceBlockSavingsString"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        og_price = None
        discount = None
    

    row = { 'Item Name': item_name.text,
            'Brand Name': brand_name.text,
            'Price': price.text,
            'URL': url
          }
    if og_price is not None:
          row["Original Price"] = og_price.text
    else:
          row["Original Price"] = "N/A"
```

Also it is a good idea to use function like find_element_by_css_selector or find_element_by_id if you have a well defined css label. We go for Xpath only when the target element does have a proper id or css label.

Comment: not sure what you mean to resolve the issue of null object exception? I want to return a null value or string "no" if the xpath doesn't exist?

Comment: @HarryKim you can just assign the object to None in case of not exists and just have a None check before accessing the text attribute. Have updated the code with that logic.

Comment: where would i exactly put the if-else statement? Also, I tried putting it before row = {'Item Name': item_name.text ...}  and I got the error "'str' object has no attribute 'text'" which I would assume is because I am calling .text on "N/A"

Comment: and when I put it after the row = {'Item Name': item_name.text ...}, I got "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: Don't do the assignment for "Original Price" within the row object initialization, only assign fields that will not be None on initial row object creation. For all other fields do the assignment using the if-else logic. As you see the above example, we are not assigning the value for field "Original Price" on initial row object creation and doing the assignment using the if-else logic below.

Comment: my god, you're a genius and a life saver. That worked wonderfully for me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy it helped you @HarryKim. Happy coding.